# Maximize The Cut Segments using top down approach?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an integer N denoting the Length of a line segment. You need to cut the line segment in such a way that the cut length of a line segment each time is either x , y or z. Here x, y, and z are integers.
After performing all the cut operations, your total number of cut segments must be maximum.
Example 1

```
Input:
N = 4
x = 2, y = 1, z = 1
Output: 4
Explanation:Total length is 4, and the cut
lengths are 2, 1 and 1.  We can make
maximum 4 segments each of length 1.
```

Example 2

```
Input:
N = 5
x = 5, y = 3, z = 2
Output: 2
Explanation: Here total length is 5, and
the cut lengths are 5, 3 and 2. We can
make two segments of lengths 3 and 2.
```

This is my solution

```
int max_seg(int M[], int n, int x, int y, int z)
{
    if( (n<=0) && (M[0] != -1) )
        return M[0];
    else if( (n>0) && M[n] != -1)
        return M[n];
        
    int q;
    if(n <= 0)
    {
        q = 0;
        M[0] = q;
        return M[0];   
    }
    else
    {
        q = max({1 + max_seg(M, n-x, x, y, z), 1 + max_seg(M, n-y, x, y, z), 1 + max_seg(M, n-y, x, y, z) });
        M[n] = q;
        return M[n];
    }
}
int maximizeTheCuts(int n, int x, int y, int z)
{
    //Your code here
    int M[n+1] = {0}; // compiler does permit this
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        M[i] = -1;
    return max_seg(M, n, x, y, z);
}
```

What is wrong with my code. Any help appreciated.
It failed for the test case below

```
N= 4000
x=3 y=4 z=5
returned 1334 instead of 1333
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger, for that specific test case? [Add that information to your question please.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66608441/edit)

Comment: `max_seg` doesn't reject a solution that makes `n` negative, and so it finds a solution that makes 1334 cuts of length 3 each; never mind that this solution would leave behind a segment of length -2. In general, your program always returns `ceil(n/min(x, y, z))`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How do I fix this. Thanks

Comment: You'd need to ensure that `max_seg` is never called with a negative `n`, or else that, if called with negative `n`, it returns a value that won't be taken as the best solution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yessssss thanks fixed it....... your suggestion was soooo helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to ensure that max_seg is never called with a negative n, or else that, if called with negative n, it returns a value that won't be taken as the best solution. – @IgorTandetnik

fix

```
int max_seg(int M[], int n, int x, int y, int z)
{
    if( (n<0) )
        return INT_MIN;
    else if( (n>=0) && M[n] != -1)
        return M[n];
        
    int q;
    if(n <= 0)
    {
        q = 0;
        M[0] = q;
        return M[0];   
    }
    else
    {
        q = max({1 + max_seg(M, n-x, x, y, z), 1 + max_seg(M, n-y, x, y, z), 1 + max_seg(M, n-y, x, y, z) });
        M[n] = q;
        return M[n];
    }
}
int maximizeTheCuts(int n, int x, int y, int z)
{
    //Your code here
    int M[n+1] = {0}; // compiler does permit this
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        M[i] = -1;
    return max_seg(M, n, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks soo much for the insight